# Is there a way to overcome the callback if(err) boilerplate in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, callback

As your project grows, we started to have this much appreciated, defensive code snippet pretty much everywhere :

```
func(err, result){
   if(err){

      console.log('An error occurred!, @myModule :' + err);
      return callback(err);
    }

    //then the rest.. 
}
```

A quick google search reveals some libs that attempt to overcome this common concern, e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/callback-wrappers.

But what is the best approach to minimize the boilerplate coding without compromising the early error handling mechanism we have?

Comment: Use promises: https://www.promisejs.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can help to alleviate this issue, both use external modules.

Firstly, and my preferred method, is to use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async), and in particular, [async.series](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback), [async.parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#paralleltasks-callback) or [async.waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall). Each of these methods will skip straight to the last function if an error occurs in any of your async calls, thus preventing the splattering of `if(err)` conditions throughout your callbacks.

For example:

```
async.waterfall([
  function(cb) {
    someAsyncOperation(cb);
  },
  function(result, cb) {
    doSomethingAsyncWithResult(result, cb);
  }
], function(err, result) {
  if(err) {
    // Handle error - could have come from any of the above function blocks
  } else {
    // Do something with overall result
  }
});
```

The other option is to use a promise library, such as [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). This has a function `Q.denodeify` to help you wrap callback-style code into promise-style. With promises, you use `.then.`, `.catch` and `.done`:

```
var qSomeAsyncOperation = Q.denodeify(someAsyncOperation);
var qDoSomethingAsyncWithResult = Q.denodeify(doSomethingAsyncWithResult);

Q()
  .then(qSomeAsyncOperation)
  .then(qDoSomethingAsyncWithResult)
  .done(function(result) {
    // Do something with overall result
  }, function(err) {
    // Handle error - could have come from any of the above function blocks
  });
```

I prefer using `async` because it is easier to understand what is going on, and it is closer to the true callback-style that node.js has adopted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! we re already using async, but still we end up with so many of if(err) checks as the number of decoupled functions and modules grow..